# Simple jQuery progressbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose: There is some cablemodems, and a man want to list their data from a MySQL database. (ip address, mac address, modemtype, ...)

Here is the HTML and PHP code: ($limit value: 15 or 25 or 50, which the user can select)

```
<table>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT ... needed fields from some tables... LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) or trigger_error( mysqli_error( $conn ) );

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
      echo "<tr class='modem_row' id='$row->modem_id' style='color:gray'>\n";
      echo "<td>$row->mac_address</td>\n";
      echo "<td>$row->ip_address</td>\n";
      echo "<td>$row->type</td>\n";
      // ...
      echo "</tr>\n";
    }

    mysqli_free_result( $result );
  ?>
</table>

<div id="progress" style="display:none; width:150px; height:20px"></div>
```

When the database query is done, then a jQuery script query all displayed modem whether they are 'online' or not (via SNMP). Here is the jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".modem_row").each(function(){
      var modem_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/modules/get_modem_state.php?modem_id="+modem_id,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'online') {
            $('#'+modem_id).animate({color: 'black'});
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

OK, it works. But i want to see the whole ajax progress in a simple HTML div. When the jQuery script begin, then it would be good the 'progress' div appear, then show the percent in a simple colored bar, and when the all ajax query done, then the 'progress' bar disappear.

(for example if $limit = 15, there is 15 ajax query. If the first query done, then the 'progress' div width will be 10px, after the second ajax query is done, the 'progress' div width will 20px, etc..)

I think that the jQuery Progressbar should I use, but I do not know how to glue together.

Comment: Mid-state progress is not easy/cut and dry to build.  How will you calculate the % complete?  The front end will need to poll something that has a denominator in order to accurately derive progress percent.   Ajax call is 0% on start or 100% on return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

```
    .progress-bar{height:20px; width:400px;}
    .status{height:20px; background:green; width:0px; text-align:center;}
    #btn{paddding:10px; width:100px; background:red;cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;}

    <div>
        <div  id="btn" onclick="Call()">click here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-bar">
       <div class="status"></div>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr id="row1" class="modem_row"><td> - </td></tr>
        <tr id="row2" class="modem_row"><td> - </td></tr>
        <tr id="row3" class="modem_row"><td> - </td></tr>
        <tr id="row4" class="modem_row"><td> - </td></tr>      
        <tr id="row5" class="modem_row"><td> - </td></tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript function:

```
    function Call(){

    var nRows = $(".modem_row").length;
    if(nRows > 0){
    var width = $(".progress-bar").width();
    var unit = width/nRows;
    var unitPercent = 100/nRows;

    var $statusDiv = $(".progress-bar").children('.status').eq(0);
    var oldWidth = 0;
    var newWidth = 0;
    var percent = 0;

    var msTimer =0;
    var count = 1;   

    $(".modem_row").each(function(){
        msTimer += 800;//miliseconds
        setTimeout(function(){ //this code should be in ajax's success function:
                oldWidth = $statusDiv.width(); 
                newWidth = oldWidth + unit;
                percent = unitPercent*count;
                //here you can use animate() with jqueryUI.
                $statusDiv.width(newWidth).text(percent + " %");                    
                count++;
        }, msTimer);

    });//each

}//if
```

}

Test it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zpmro9y/1/).

Define a width for progress bar and the script will detect it and will calculate how much must increment.

Comment: yes, this way really work, i will post the final code.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any loading image. Create your own loading image here: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Then modify your code:

```
<div class="loader" style="display:none;">
    <img src="loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".modem_row").each(function(){
      var modem_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".loader").show();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/modules/get_modem_state.php?modem_id="+modem_id,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'online') {
            $(".loader").hide();
            $('#'+modem_id).animate({color: 'black'});
          }
        },
        error: function(){
            $(".loader").hide();
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

You need to add the image in the `<img />` tag.

If you want to use jQuery UI Progress Bar, then you would have to set the "request duration" manually. The request might finish before the duration you set, or after the duration you set. In both cases, it's a poor user experience.

Here's a link to setup jQuery UI Progress Bar: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label

There's no way you can get the exact duration for the request (request to DB + request to Server + processing + memory + CPU ... a lot of factors), except when you're loading a Flash file. Flash has a technique to calculate the size of all its components which are loaded on the stage and it can give you a precise real-time progress bar. It doesn't make sense to use it unless you're building a Flash application.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a solution using jQuery UI Progress Bar:

```
    <div class="loader" style="display:none;">
    <div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var progress_duration = 2000;
    var total_number_of_items = 15;

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: false,
        change: function() {
            var percent = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%";
            $(".progress-label").text(percent);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".progress-label").text("Complete");
        }
    });

    function calculateProgress(){
        var val = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value") || 0;
        var step = Math.round(100 / total_number_of_items);
        var new_val = val + step;
        if(new_val > 100) new_val = 100;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", new_val);
        if(val < 99){
            setTimeout(calculateProgress, 80);
        }
    }

    function animateProgressBar(){
        setTimeout(calculateProgress, progress_duration);
    }

    $(".modem_row").each(function(){
        var modem_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/modules/get_modem_state.php?modem_id="+modem_id,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'online'){
                    animateProgressBar();
                    $('#'+modem_id).animate({color: 'black'});
                }
            },
            error: function(){

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and here's some CSS code:

```
.ui-progressbar {
    position: relative;
}
.progress-label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

Comment: I dont want use image, but a simple HTML colored div.

Comment: Ok use whatever you want. The idea is to show the div before calling the AJAX call, and to hide it when "onsuccess" and "onerror".

Comment: @szpal I edited the code and added a solution using jQuery UI Progress Bar. Keep in mind that you need to include the jQuery UI library. Here's the link: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label

Comment: thanks for this. I got a smoother svg loader from http://samherbert.net/svg-loaders

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for AiApaec, the final working simple progressbar:
(the modified js/html code..)

```
<style>
  .progress-bar { height:10px; width:200px }
  .status { height:10px; background:silver; width:0px }
</style>

<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="status"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var nRows = $(".modem_row").length;
    if ( nRows > 0) {
      var width = $(".progress-bar").width();
      var unit = width/nRows;
      var $statusDiv = $(".progress-bar").children('.status').eq(0);
      var oldWidth = 0;
      var newWidth = 0;
      var i = 0;

      $(".modem_row").each(function(){
        var modem_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
          url: "/modules/get_modem_state.php?modem_id="+modem_id,
          success: function(data) {
            oldWidth = $statusDiv.width(); 
            newWidth = oldWidth + unit;
            $statusDiv.width(newWidth);                    
            if ( ++i == nRows ) {
              $('.status').fadeOut();
            }
            if (data == 'online') {
              $('#'+modem_id).animate({color: 'black'});
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

I hope it will help others.